# Run application only for users with license

Tags: wpf, api, arcgis

How to run WPF application for users with purchased ArcGIS licenses only?
In other words to find installed license with using of API.

Comment: add a login screen? your question is quite vague

Comment: How about consulting the ArcGIS SDK documentation? What did you try?

Comment: @FredrikRedin Question is updated.

Comment: @Clemens  I didn't found an answer in ArcGIS SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can either embed the license in the application so it gets packaged and then can be run or you can let the user login with their organisational account user which unlocks the standard license level. Otherwise it will run as a basic level license. There isn't a way to detect a user's license as the SDK licensing is separate to the desktop licensing.